# Material UI and Bootstrap for desktop and mobile

Tags: node.js, mobile, bootstrap-4, material-ui, desktop

Are there settings to respect when working with the Material UI Table when it comes to desktop and mobile views?

I have a Material UI Table that looks fine in the desktop view. It also looks fine when toggling the device toolbar to a mobile view. But when I access the same table with Chrome on an Android or Safari on an iPhone, the table graphics break.

How can this be solved?

### ***Table Code:***

```
import { Typography, Paper, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

...

public render() {
    return <div className='mask-task-list'>
        <Typography variant='h4' component='h2' className='header'>{this.maskTitle()}</Typography>
        <Paper className='scrollable-paper'>
            <Table className='table-min-width' aria-label='simple table' size='small'>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell'>Company</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell'>Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell'>Start</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell'>Stop</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell'>Comment</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell edit-column'>Edit</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='table-header-cell delete-column'>Delete</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                {this.renderTasks(this.state.taskList)}
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    </div>;
}
```

### ***CSS in use:***

```
.scrollable-paper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-min-width {
    min-width: 650;
}
```

### ***Versions in use:***

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.6.1",
"@types/react": "16.9.11",
"@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
"bootstrap": "4.3.1",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-dom": "16.11.0",
"typescript": "3.7.4",
```

### ***Desktop View (looks fine):***

[image: desktop view]

### ***Mobile on Desktop View (looks fine):***

[image: mobile on desktop view]

### ***Mobile View 1 (breaks on the right side):***

[image: mobile view 1]

### ***Mobile View 2 (breaks on the right side):***

[image: mobile view 2]